# What does this array-style destructuring on a function do in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, redux-actions

I read through the [`redux-actions` tutorial](https://redux-actions.js.org/introduction/tutorial), and am confused by their use of (what I believe to be) destructuring. Below is an example (`increment` & `decrement` are both functions returned by the `createAction` function).

```
const { createAction, handleActions } = window.ReduxActions;

const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [increment]: state => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 }),
    [decrement]: state => ({ ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 })
  },
  defaultState
);
```

Here's another example of this being used:

```
const { createActions, handleActions, combineActions } = window.ReduxActions;
​
const reducer = handleActions(
  {
    [combineActions(increment, decrement)]: (
      state,
      { payload: { amount } }
    ) => {
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter + amount };
    }
  },
  defaultState
);
```

Can somebody explain what's happening in those lines? In simplified terms, I just see `{[function]: () => ({})}`, and don't understand what this does.

Comment: And I should note: I've looked through the full MDN article on destructuring and found nothing, and don't really know what else to look for.

Comment: That's not destructuring, that's a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

Comment: Voted to reopen to explain the difference using a function as a computed property name makes. Can't help wondering whether that performance hit is negligible on low-power devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's indeed a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), but with a twist - a function is used as a key, not a string.

It might look confusing until you remember that each function can be safely cast to string - the result is that function's source code. And that's exactly what happens here:

```
function x() {}
const obj = { [x]: 42 };
console.log( obj[x] ); // 42
console.log( obj[x.toString()] ); // 42, key is the same actually
console.log( Object.keys(obj) );  // ["function x() {}"]
```

The advantage of such approach is that you don't need to create additional keys - if you have a function reference, you already have one. In fact, you don't even have to have a reference - it's enough to have a function with the same source:

```
const one = () => '';
const two = () => '';
console.log(one === two); // false apparently 
const fatArrObj = { [one]: 42 } 
fatArrObj[two]; // 42, take that Oxford scholars!!
```

The disadvantage is that function is cast to string each time it's used as key - a (supposedly minor) performance hit.

---

To add some fun, this is valid object literal:

```
{ 
   [null]: null, // access either with [null] or ['null']
   [undefined]: undefined, 
   [{ toString: () => 42 }]: 42 // access with, you guess it, 42 (or '42')
}
```

... and this one might go into book of weird interview questions:

```
const increment = (() => { let x = 0; return () => ++x })();
const movingTarget = { toString: increment };
const weirdObjectLiteral = { [movingTarget]: 42 };
console.log( weirdObjectLiteral[movingTarget] ); // undefined
```

Comment: so does that last "weird interview question" bit end up as `undefined` because `movingTarget` is is an object?

Comment: What makes this tick is its `toString()` implementation - it returns different value each time it's called. That's why the name, _movingTarget_. )

Comment: oh - would this be different if we used `[toString]` instead of `toString` as the key?

Comment: No, it would just use global `toString` function (defined on `window`) as key.

Comment: Hmm I'm not following. Could you elaborate a bit more? Would using the global `toString` via a computed property name (`[window.toString]` for clarity) work? How about `[toString]` instead of the explicit `window.toString`? I'm confused as to why the `toString` implementation would constantly change..

Comment: ooooh or is it because of the `()` at the end of the `increment` line that i just noticed?

Comment: and then is that because every time you reference `increment`, it'll increment - because that `()` is part of variable?

Comment: this is pretty neat. never knew you could do stuff like this with js!! thanks for sharing :)

Comment: could help me understand why the `increment` function runs when we run `console.log( weirdObjectLiteral[movingTarget] );`, but not when we run `console.log( movingTarget );`? I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around that.

Comment: Because `console.log` doesn't use `toString()` for objects, using its own representation mechanism.

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding this, so I'm going to ask a new stackoverflow question. :) I'll tag you in it.

Comment: now that i've posted my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129884/why-does-this-really-tricky-computed-property-name-function-works-the-way-it-doe), i think it finally clicked for me. if we use `[toString]` - we have the `toString` return value in that moment used as the key forever. with `toString`, the return value keeps changing. I still am surprised that this value keeps changing though... does it depend on `Date.now()` or `Math.random()` or anything like that?