# Why does this really tricky computed property name function works the way it does?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, computed-properties

@raina77ow recently helped me figure out computed property names. As part of [their answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52123120/798491), they shared a really tricky bit of code showcasing interesting aspects of JavaScript:

```
const increment = (() => { let x = 0; return () => ++x })();
const movingTarget = { toString: increment };
const weirdObjectLiteral = { [movingTarget]: 42 };
console.log( weirdObjectLiteral[movingTarget] ); // undefined
```

When I run that sample in the node CLI, that last line continually outputs `undefined`, while the value `x` in `increment` continually increments.

If we replace `const movingTarget = { toString: increment };` with `const movingTarget = { [toString]: increment };`, this behaviour ceases to take place, and instead we get an output of `42` and the `x` in `increment` remains the same.

Can somebody help me understand why this is the case? What is it about JavaScript that makes things work this way?

*Related Question*: Does the `x` in the function within `increment` exist until we explicitly remove `increment` from memory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets evaluate the following object literal:

```
 {[toString]: increment }
```

`toString` is an identifier pointing to `window.toString` (a function) As outlined by the answer, `toString` will be called on that as object keys are always strings:

```
 {[toString.toString()]: increment }
```

Now that results in something like:

```
 {["function() { [native code] }"]: increment }
```

Now if we call `toString()` on this object, the standard `Object.prototype.toString` will get called in the `{[movingTarget]: 42}` part and the result is `[Object object]` (as always):

```
 let x = 0;
 let movingTarget = { ["function() { [native code] }"]: () => ++x };

 console.log(
  movingTarget.toString(), // [Object object]
  {[movingTarget]: 42} // {["[Object object]"]: 42}
 );
```

thats why the moving target isnt moving anymore. In the original code, `toString` of the object was set, and that gets called whenever `movingTarget` gets turned into a string:

```
 let x = 0;
 let movingTarget = { toString: () => ++x };
 console.log(
   movingTarget.toString(), // 1
   "" + movingTarget, // 2
  {[movingTarget]: 42} // { 3: 42 }
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's dilute the complication a little bit by slightely changing the example. The following example is basically the same thing as `toString` is called every time `movingTarget` is evaluated, so we'll just get rid of it and call the function ourselves:

```js
let x = 0;
let func = () => ++x;

const weirdObjectLiteral = { [func()]: 42 };   // equivalent to weirdObjectLiteral = { "1": 42 }

console.log( weirdObjectLiteral[func()] );     // equivalent to weirdObjectLiteral["2"]
```

See? The first time we called `func`, the value it returned was `1`, so the "computed" property is `"1"`. In the second time we called `func`, the returned value was `2`, we tried accessing that and got `undefined` back because there is no property `"2"`.

**How is this related to the example in the question?**

It is related because in the original code we are using `movingTarget` as both the value of the computed property and the key to access that property. Since both of them are expecting strings, `movingTarget` is coerced into a string by calling its `toString` method. This `toString` method is defined as a function that increment `x` and returns its new value (i.e. the inner function returned by the IIFE, the function `() => ++x`). So basically whenever we used `movingTarget` as either a computed property value or a key, that function is called and its return value was used.

Comment: ... equivalent to `weirdObjectLiteral["2"]`, actually; hence `undefined`. But overall, I like the explanation. )

Comment: ooooooh it's because you're resetting what it's `toString` function is!!! d'oh, ok now this makes sense for me!

Comment: Hey so this is the answer that made it click for me that we are overriding `toString` for that object - if you edit this so that it's more accurate (as per raina77ow's comment), i'll accept this.